# Best Way to Use a Custom Font-Family Without Load Effect?

Tags: css, font-face

I've added my own custom font and used the code below to get a custom font-family to display, however, there seems to be an issue where as the page is loading the font starts off as a web standard font then quickly updates to the custom font I've added.

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
font-family:linto;
src:url(achafsex/Achafexp.eot);
}
@font-face{
font-family:linto;
src:url(achafsex/Achafexp.ttf);
}
div{
font-family:linto;
font-size:100px;
width:500px;
}
</style>
```

Is there a better code to do this so that the custom font loads instantly with the page and doesn't have the obvious changing effect?

Answer (score 1):

Try.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'linto';
src: url('linto.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('linto.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('linto.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('linto.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('linto.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Then when you specify it, try using:

```
 div {
 font-family: 'linto', Fallback, sans-serif;
 }
```

The only problem I see, is its first loading from the `body` font first, then it then loads your fontface.

Try using:
`body {
     font-family: 'linto', Fallback, sans-serif;
     }`, first to see if this fixes your load problem, I don't agree with having multiple styles on one sheet.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios like this - I'll usually use a "cover" div that is @ the highest Z-index and then once the page has completed loading, I will remove it, revealing the page. The trick is figuring out a good way of polling the end user for completion of component download. Good luck!